# Direction of two parallel lines in 3D

Tags: vector-spaces

Suppose I have two lines $A$ and $B$ in space then we can find it's direction by finding the direction ratios of any vector on or parallel to them . If we have $2$ parallel vectors then will their direction ratios be same?

My teacher told me that we can consider that but my textbook gives me the formula that their direction ratios will be proportional so can anybody elaborate this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it makes any difference for the direction ratios to be (a,b,c)    or   (ra,rb,rc) because the ratio a:b:c = ra:rb:rc remains the same. .Any vector or line can have infinite direction ratios but they all tell us the same thing.Even parallel vectors have same direction ratios inspite of one of them being a scalar multiple of other.So both your book and teacher is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Since any two parallel vectors have their direction ratios in proportion so we can say that their direction ratio hence their direction is same.